# How to add images in CartoDB infowindows

Tags: carto, web-mapping, image

Can't seem to get the default site to display images.

I've added HTML anchor hrefs to a image column, for example:

```
<a href="http:\\website\image1.png"></a>
```

I've dragged the image column to the top of the infowindow sidebar app and it still just displays "Non-valid picture URL". I also can't seem to figure out the last sentence of the explanation.

The explanation is:

*Adding images to your infowindows
This template allows you to add an image to your infowindow.  The image URLs will need to be stored as a column in your table. Next, you will need to drag the URL field to the top of your infowindow and then select 'Header with image'.*

Answer (score 1):

You can see an **example** of how to add images to the info windows on [The Hobbit Locations](http://cartodb.github.io/cartodb.js/examples/TheHobbitLocations/) map. And you have the [source code](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/tree/develop/examples/TheHobbitLocations) to check how to do it on GitHub.

The template definition (plain HTML or [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/)) is on the [index.html](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/TheHobbitLocations/index.html#L41) page:

```
<!--Custom html for the infowindow customization-->
<!--You can write simple html or use Mustache templates http://mustache.github.com/-->
<!--Content.data contains the field info-->
<script type="infowindow/html" id="infowindow_template">
  <div class="cartodb-popup">
    <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
     <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
       <div class="cartodb-popup-cont">
        <img src="{{content.data.pic}}" />
        <h4>{{content.data.name_to_display}}</h4>
        {{#content.data.video_url}}
          <a class="videoButton" href="{{content.data.video_url}}" target="_blank"> </a>
        {{/content.data.video_url}}
        <p>{{content.data.description}}</p>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
  </div>
</script>
```